# Choosing an open source Continuous Delivery solution for programming education

Tags: automation, unit-tests, performance-analysis, continuous-integration, static-analysis

In my Business Informatics Bachelor thesis I have chosen a topic, in which I have to set up a Continuous Delivery (that must be open source) server which students can use in their programming eudcation, especially in Software Engineering group projects. Students shall be able to easily copy (probably with Docker if I enough have time left to configure it) the server which I set up respectivley it should be easy to reproduce with my documentation.

There are no explicit requirements concerning the programming languages which can be handled by the CD server, but Java is a must have since almost all our courses about programming fundamentals are taught with Java.

The server which I set up **must include the following features** (some of them probably must be added through Plugins or Addons):

- Build Automation
- Static Code Analysis
- Automatic execution of Performance tests
- Automatic execution of Unit tests
- Visualization of the test results

I now must choose a solution that can bring all of these features (and which is open source and easy to copy, not to forget). So far, I came to three options*** for that:

1. Build Bot
2. GoCD
3. Hudson

Which solution can provide me all the listed features? Which one would yo pick if you would have to implement a system with my requirements?

*** Don't pin me down because Jenkins is not listed here but I have a reason why I search for alternatives (can explain later if you are curious). I know that Jenkins is a great tool and could provide all features but I find it interesting anyway to provide a different solution, even if it is just for diversity's sake.

Comment: For Hudson, you would be far better recommended to go with its fork Jenkins (forked by the original author, after a trademark dispute, all major plugin developers joined him & abandoned Hudson. This was years ago & Jenkins is stable, popular, maintained and well documented).  I ***like**** Jenkins & woudl choose nothing else

Answer (score -1):

I would like to reference you to ProductionMap. It's a cool startup for automation development and execution. It's an open source IDE where you can develop and execute automation on large scale of servers and services.

You can contact them directly at support@productionmap.com
The website is [www.productionmap.com](http://www.productionmap.com).

Disclosure: I'm the CEO / founder.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Ilan! Could you do another one and show how ProductionMap meets the requirements listed in the question, plus what are the costs? See our [answer guideline](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for hints what an answer should contain ;)